# Can men travel in female only couchette compartments?

Tags: trains, europe, bookings, austria, venice

This may seem like a stupid question- but I'm traveling with my family on an overnight train. The only seats available are female only couchettes. This journey is essential to our trip, and there are no other seats available. We are 2 men and 2 women. What happens if men travel in such couchettes? Is there a fine? Can they be accommodated in another compartment appropriate for them on the day of the journey? Will they not be allowed to board the train?

Comment: How large are the couchettes? If there are only four beds / seats in one couchette, you might get lucky and get one all to yourselves - and I could imagine that the conductor does not care as long as all passengers are happy. OTOH, if they are larger and you have to share, you better be prepared for hassle (although I have no idea what the consequences might look like)

Comment: Couchettes are usually mixed as it is not customary to get undressed. Are you sure these are segregated?

Comment: Unfortunately these couchettes are segregated, and the train is pretty much sold out- there’s no other couchettes available- so I definitely can’t get a private compartment.

Comment: @mdewey With ÖBB / Nightjet, they are not segregated but you get two options: mixed or female-only (no male-only option and no obligation not to share a compartment with people of another gender).

Comment: @VPrah Quite apart from any fine, if you cannot get a private compartment, it would be increasingly hostile to the other passengers in the female-only compartment. Just don't do it.

Comment: We are a family of 4- unfortunately only 6 bed couchette was available. I totally understand and would never violate the rights of other passengers intentionally but this is a unique situation- my trip bookings are all non- refundable and we have only limited days everywhere so day trip by train would mean we can’t do the things planned.

Comment: The reality is that unfortunately those trains are often fully booked well in advance, I have occasionally been unable to rely on them when I needed it, nothing exceptional about that. So since there are simply no tickets available to you, you should proceed accordingly.

Comment: @VPrah Not being able to do things as planned sounds to me as an awfully poor, but very egoistic reason to ignore the rights and expectations of the the two females ending up in the last beds in your compartment. If it is essential for you to get from A to B overnight and there are nothing suitable free in the night train, you probably have the option to take a taxi. Yes, that may be much more expensive, but it is not that you don't have any other options here and for some reason should find it legit to trespass on others privacy.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo your lack of understanding on this is surprising. My parents are senior citizens and my priority is their comfort. It’s definitely not an egoistic reason. As a woman myself I know how important it is to be cognisant of such matters. Besides I’m sharing my problems and requesting solutions. If taxi for a 6 hour journey would be okay for my parents I wouldn’t mind paying extra. Please understand my situation. it’s not like we’ll barge into a woman’s compartment and demand to stay. i was hoping to reason with the conductor or with fellow passengers for seat exchange.

Comment: @relaxed I don't know this, but are the female only couchettes segregated within specific cars?  Or can a single car have a mix of mixed and female only couchettes?

Comment: This is a nice question- I’ll know which car to request exchange in etc through this. Another question- are there any sleeper buses- the nice high quality ones that will make such a journey?

Answer (score 7):

That's hard to predict.

- You may not be able to book the ticket, if your gender is on file (in your profile) or they specifically ask to confirm that you are female. I recommend against intentionally lying.
- Even if you have a ticket, it's quite likely that you being male violates the terms and conditions of the ticket, so it could be interpreted as invalid.
- In this case it probably comes down to the individual conductor. They may be fine with it if you all are one family and agree, they may move you to a different place, or they kick you off the train.

Comment: Since OP has clarified in the comments that it is a 6-berth compartment and they are only four people, I would suggest "They may be fine with it if you all are one family and agree" doesn't apply here. Unless of course they book two extra "phantom" people in the same compartment.

Comment: I would be happy to book the 2 extra and pay for those if they were available. The train is full :(

Comment: Since the other two are not available, the probability is high that they were booked by female people who expect a female-only space.

Comment: I have booked a private sitting compartment for the 2 men since I’m out of options. Now I have a new problem- I have a reservation for 4 people in the women only couchette. I want to cancel 2 and keep 2. But the website is only allowing me to cancel all 4 together. What if after cancellation I don’t get 2 tickets? I’m unable to contact ÖBB as well- is there any solution?

Comment: @VPrah That's a totally different question, and you should post it as a new question rather than as a comment here.  Also, one of your possible solutions was to buy the two extra tickets anyway, so eating that extra cost could be better than risking losing those spots.

Comment: That makes sense- Thanks @PeterM. If only contacting Obb was possible it would solve my problems

Comment: @VPrah Contacting ÖBB is very much possible: they have a customer service telephone number on their website, and they are relatively responsive in my experience. I don't know if they offer it in English though.